# ¿Por qué los campos de mi formulario HTML no se envían a la base de datos?

Tags: php, html

Verán, he estado trabajando en la creación de una pagina web en `HTML` y `PHP`, en ella tengo que hacer un formulario con varios controles (como lo son el `radio`, `checkbox`, `select`, `tareatexto`) que tienen que enviarse a una base de datos.

Cuando ingreso datos al formulario y los envió, logro que me aparezca el mensaje "Se han enviado los datos correctamente" pero cuando reviso mi base de datos, no aparece ningún dato que había ingresado en mi pagina web.

¿Me podrían decir que estoy haciendo mal?

código `HTML`:

```html
   <form action="opcion.php" method="post">
   
   <center><Font size="5" color="black" face="Monotype Corsiva">Ingresa tu nombre</font></size></center>
   <center><input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="andrea.."></center>
   <br>
   <br>
   <center><font size="5" color="black" face="Monotype Corsiva">Ingresa tu apellido</font></size></center>
   <center><input type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Lopez.."></center>
   <br>
   <br>
   <center><Font size="5" color="black" face="Monotype Corsiva">Ingresa tu e-mail</font></size></center>
   <center><input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="yosoy@gmail.com"></center>
   <br>
   <br>
   <center><Font size="5" color="black" face="Monotype Corsiva">Ingresa tu contraseña</font></size></center>
   <center><input type="text" name="pw" placeholder="......"></center>
  <BR>
  <BR>
   <center><Font size="5" color="black" face="Monotype Corsiva">Selecciona tu sexo</font></size></center>
   <BR>
   <br>
 <CENTER><select name="sexo">
   <option name="sexo"value="Mujer">Mujer</option>
   <option name="sexo" value="Hombre">Hombre</option>
   </select>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
   <center><Font size="5" color="black" face="Monotype Corsiva">selecciona tu edad</font></size></center>
  <br>
   <br>
<select name="edad">
<option name="edad" value="tres">0-15
<option name="edad" value="dos">15-40
<option name="edad" value="tres">40 o mas
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <center><Font size="5" color="black" face="Monotype Corsiva">Te gusta mi pagina?</font></size></center>
   <CENTER><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="no">No
   <CENTER><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="si">Si
   <br>
   <br>
   <center><font size="5" color="black" face="Monotype Corsiva">Deja un comentario</font></size></center>
   <br>
   <BR>
   <CENTER><textarea name="comentario"></textarea>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <font size="4" color="black" face="Monotype Corsiva"> Por que entraste a mi pagina?, elige todas las opciones que desees<size></font>
     <input type="checkbox"  name="1" value="me gusto" >Me gusto
     <input type="checkbox"  name="1" value="Me llamo la atencion">Me llamo la atencion
  <input type="checkbox"  name="1" value="Porquesi">Porque si
   <center><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></center>
```

Código php:

```
 <?php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos =$_POST['apellidos'];
$mail= $_POST['mail'];
$pw = $_POST['pw'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$edad = $_POST['edad'];
$gustar = $_POST['radio1'];
$comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
$razon = $_POST['1'];
$puerto = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$contraseña = "";
$conexion = mysql_connect($puerto,$usuario,$contraseña);                                                                
mysql_select_db("info2",$conexion);
$insertar = "insert into datos(nombre,apellidos,mail,contraseña,sexo,edad,gustar,comentario,razon) values ('$nombre','$apellidos','$mail','$pw','$sexo','$edad','$gustar','$comentario','$razon')";
mysql_query($insertar);
echo "Se han enviado los datos exitosamente"; 
<?
```

Comment: Qué versión de `PHP` usas? La extensión `mysql_connect` está declarada obsoleta y fue removida en `PHP 7`. Revisa [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php) en el sitio oficial de `PHP`

Comment: te sugiero revisar lo siguiente y por seguridad y actualizacion ya no debes usar mysql...sino mysqli o PDO: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_insert_query.htm

Comment: un link mas completo: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: Duda, estás usando xampp o wampserver? Esto podría aclarar a las dudas para los demás que puedan ayudarte. Por cierto, mysqli o PDO es bien recomendado para este caso del envío al base de datos. Un saludo.

Comment: Que tal Natali, bienvenida... Como te dijeron anteriormente, mysql_connect() solo funciona en versiones anteriores a PHP7... Te recomiendo verifiques la versión de PHP con la que estás trabajando...

Comment: muchas gracias por responder. Estoy usando wampserver.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Datos de la base de datos
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "alumnos";

// creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

// Selección del a base de datos a utilizar
$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );
// establecer y realizar consulta. guardamos en variable.
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM alumnos";
$resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

// Motrar el resultado de los registro de la base de datos
// Encabezado de la tabla
echo "<table borde='2'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Nombre</th>";
echo "<th>Edad</th>";
echo "</tr>";

// Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $columna['nombre'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['edad'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>"; // Fin de la tabla
// cerrar conexión de base de datos
mysqli_close( $conexion );
```

?>

Comment: checa este ejemplo ....  este lo acabo de ocupar en una mini prueba..

Comment: La OP no ocupa mysqli, sino mysql, deberías indicar si todo el código es retro compatible

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestarme, pero aun así no me llega  a la base de datos, no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: como tienes tu conexion?

Comment: utilicé el código que me proporcionó, soló que le modifiqué algunas cosas, como el nombre de la base de datos, y le agregue mas registros.

Comment: ?  segura??   eso esta en internet y lo ocupe..

checate los puertos....

Comment: Por qué este código resuelve la pregunta? Podrías añadir una breve explicación para que quien pregunta y todos los que lean después, sepan qué hacer para resolver el problema

Comment: Mi pregunta es, si el código de mi formulario y el de la conexión con la base de datos es correcta, ya que no me parece nada en cuando reviso la base de datos .